# why ffmpeg process successfully terminated with return code of 1 without play anything

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, bots, audio-player

`I tried replacing youtube_dl with yt_dlp and replaced some of the code, the code worked fine but when using the command, the bot doesn't play music but immediately ffmpeg process 15076 successfully terminated with return code of 1

Is there a problem with my code or the ffmpg option or ytdlp option that doesn't support the yt_dlp library?`

```
 self.YTDL_OPTIONS = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'outtmpl': 'F:/DISCORD BOT/Ex/music/%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        'restrictfilenames': True,
        'retry_max': 'auto',
        'noplaylist': True,
        'nocheckcertificate': True,
        'ignoreerrors': True,
        'logtostderr': False,
        'quiet': True,
        'no_warnings': True,
        'default_search': 'auto',
        'source_address': '0.0.0.0',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
        'youtube_api_key': 'api'
    }
self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
         'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
         'options': '-vn',
         'executable':r'F:\DISCORD BOT\Ex\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe'
         }

    
    @commands.hybrid_command(
        name="play",
        aliases=["p"],
        usage="<song_title_or_youtube_url>",
        description="KARAUKENAN.",
         
    )
    @app_commands.describe(
        judul_lagu="link ato judul lagunya"
    )
    async def play(self, ctx, judul_lagu:str):
        await ctx.defer()
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice
        if not voice_channel or not voice_channel.channel:
            await ctx.send("Join voice channel dulu gblk!")
            return

        voice_channel = voice_channel.channel
        song = self.search_song(judul_lagu)
        if not song:
            await ctx.send("Lagnya tdk ditemukan, coba keword lain.")
            return

        if not self.bot.voice_clients:
            voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            voice_client = self.bot.voice_clients[0]
            if voice_client.channel != voice_channel:
                await voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

        self.music_queue.append([song, voice_client])
        if not self.is_playing:
            await self.play_music(ctx)
    
    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        self.is_playing = True
        while len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            song = self.music_queue[0][0]
            voice_client = self.music_queue[0][1]
            await ctx.send(f"Playing {song['title']}")

            voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song['source'], **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
            voice_client.is_playing()

            while voice_client.is_playing():
                await asyncio.sleep(1)

            self.music_queue.pop(0)
            self.is_playing = False

        await ctx.send("Queue is empty.")
        voice_client.stop()

    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = False

    def search_song(self, judul_lagu):
        ydl = yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(self.YTDL_OPTIONS)
        with ydl:
            try:
                info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{judul_lagu}", download=False)['entries'][0]
                return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}
            except Exception:
                return None
```

when i use /play the bot sucess serch song but immediately terminate does not play any music

```
2023-04-10 13:06:45 INFO     discord.voice_client Connecting to voice...
2023-04-10 13:06:45 INFO     discord.voice_client Starting voice handshake... (connection attempt 1)
2023-04-10 13:06:46 INFO     discord.voice_client Voice handshake complete. Endpoint found singapore11075.discord.media
2023-04-10 13:06:50 INFO     discord.player ffmpeg process 15076 successfully terminated with return code of 1.
```

[this image whe i use /play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nrUQ.png)

Answer (score -1):

just remove the **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS param in your play() method, that worked for me :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).